# Calculation does not match the join table

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a problem with my query, using sum or count data by join multiple tables, the results of the query should not match, the result is multiplied, What should I consider when calculating the data using a join multiple tables, it is enough to make me confused

like this :

i have 4 Tables that are interconnected

```
select T3.series,  
sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'JAN 13', 
sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'FEB 13', 
sum(If(Month = 3 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'MAR 13'
From Typemotor T3
LEFT JOIN (
select T.Series,Month(C.Date) as Month,Year(C.Date) as Year,
Count(T.Series) as Jumlah
from 
(select a.Type, a.Date,a.MachineNumber
from 
selling_cash a
left join lokasi b
on a.Showr = b.KodeLokasi
where b.PT = 'PT MERDEKA'
group by a.MachineNumber)
as C
Left Join Typeconvert T2
on C.Type = T2.TypeSystem
Left Join Typemotor T
on T2.TypeConv = T.Type
Group by T.Series,Month,Year ) as R
On R.Series = T3.Series
Group by T3.Series order by T3.Series asc;
```

The Result is :

```
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+  
| series             | JAN 13 | FEB 13 | MAR 13 |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| AUTOMATIC LPM      |  13068 |   9416 |  10648 |
| AUTOMATIC PREMIUM  |    187 |    506 |    330 |
| AUTOMATIC STANDART |  11502 |  12690 |  10206 |
| JUPITER SERIES     |   3584 |   3360 |   3360 |
| LEXAM              |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| MX SERIES          |   3456 |   1664 |   3200 |
| SPORT              |   9620 |   7852 |   7826 |
| VEGA SERIES        |   2808 |   1728 |   1080 |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

should result was

```
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| series             | JAN 13 | FEB 13 | MAR 13 |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| AUTOMATIC LPM      |     33 |     28 |     38 |
| AUTOMATIC PREMIUM  |      3 |      9 |      6 |
| AUTOMATIC STANDART |     35 |     41 |     32 |
| JUPITER SERIES     |     22 |     20 |     20 |
| LEXAM              |      0 |      0 |      0 |
| MX SERIES          |     27 |     13 |     25 |
| SPORT              |     80 |     64 |     64 |
| VEGA SERIES        |     13 |      8 |      5 |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

is there any advice, point point what needs to be considered to perform calculations / sum with join tables so that the result is correct?

Comment: Kinda hard to tell without seeing the database, but have you tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`? Example: `From Typemotor T3 INNER JOIN (`

Comment: thank you jerdiggity, already join (inner, cross, rihgt, extc) I try, the result is still the same. sorry I did not include the database, maybe should I do first instance, and then recently I asked, thank you, best wishes from Semarang :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a mysql person, but I'd make a few observations about your query.

First I can see no point in the clause "group by a.MachineNumber" because this query contains no aggregate function.

I repeat your query here for clarity:

```
select T3.series,  
  sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'JAN 13', 
  sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'FEB 13', 
  sum(If(Month = 3 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'MAR 13'
From Typemotor T3
  LEFT JOIN (select T.Series, Month(C.Date) as Month, Year(C.Date) as Year, Count(T.Series) as Jumlah
        from (
          select a.Type, a.Date, a.MachineNumber 
          from selling_cash a left join lokasi b on a.Showr = b.KodeLokasi
          where b.PT = 'PT MERDEKA'
          group by a.MachineNumber
        ) as C
          Left Join Typeconvert T2 on C.Type = T2.TypeSystem
          Left Join Typemotor T on T2.TypeConv = T.Type
        Group by T.Series, Month, Year
  ) as R On R.Series = T3.Series
Group by T3.Series 
order by T3.Series asc;
```

It seems to me that the left joins to Typeconvert & Typemotor could both be moved into the definition of C, and since you're only interested in data for 2013, months 1-3, these conditions could be added to the where clause inside C at which point the data that C needs to provide to the parent query is reduced to Series, MonthNumber & Jumlah:

```
select T3.series,  
  sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'JAN 13', 
  sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'FEB 13', 
  sum(If(Month = 3 and Year = 2013,jumlah,0)) as 'MAR 13'
From Typemotor T3
  LEFT JOIN (
    select Series, MonthNumber, Count(*) as Jumlah
    from (
      select T.Series, Month(a.Date) as MonthNumber 
      from selling_cash a 
        left join lokasi b on a.Showr = b.KodeLokasi
        left Join Typeconvert T2 on C.Type = T2.TypeSystem
        left Join Typemotor T on T2.TypeConv = T.Type
      where b.PT = 'PT MERDEKA' and year(a.Date) = 2013 and month(a.date) <= 3
    ) as C
  Group by Series, MonthNumber
  ) as R On R.Series = T3.Series
Group by T3.Series 
order by T3.Series asc;
```

However now is the inner query (R) not generating the data that you want? Is there still a need to sum it?

Since you havent provided the table definitions you have, and sample data contained in them, I cannot answer this. But I think it is something you need to consider re why the answer you expect isnt what your query gives.

I think it is more likely that the logic is not quite right, than that there is some unknown.

Thus I think the final query should be:

```
select T3.series,  
  If(MonthNumber = 1,jumlah,0) as 'JAN 13', 
  If(MonthNumber = 2,jumlah,0) as 'FEB 13', 
  If(MonthNumber = 3,jumlah,0) as 'MAR 13'
From Typemotor T3
  LEFT JOIN (
    select Series, MonthNumber, Count(*) as Jumlah
    from (
      select T.Series, Month(a.Date) as MonthNumber 
      from selling_cash a 
        left join lokasi b on a.Showr = b.KodeLokasi
        left Join Typeconvert T2 on C.Type = T2.TypeSystem
        left Join Typemotor T on T2.TypeConv = T.Type
      where b.PT = 'PT MERDEKA' and year(a.Date) = 2013 and month(a.date) <= 3
    ) as C
  Group by Series, MonthNumber
  ) as R On R.Series = T3.Series
order by T3.Series asc;
```

Comment: Tq John , I was supposed to includes its database, but too much data, so I had to make an example of the data used,. In any case thanks for your response, your idea above I tried to apply,

Comment: Fun, can give me an alternative way of logic, I'll try .. Thank you :)